# upload file from local website to blob storage

Tags: php, azure

I want to upload files from local storage to the Azure blob container. Below is the PHP code that is failing.

I am using XAMPP as a local server.
I have created a local web page that uploads files to the local MySQL server and a container on Azure blob storage.

The below code fails when I try to upload a file. (however, if I remove the part of code that uploads to azure blob, then the code works perfectly fine and the files upload to the local MySQL server.) I am facing a problem in uploading the files to Azure Blob

```
<?php
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
  use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
  
  // If the upload button is clicked ... 
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    //upload to azure blob container

    //Enter deployment key
    $connectionString = ""; 

    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
    $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $tmp = explode('.' , $file_name);
    $extension = end($tmp);
    $file_name = mt_rand().".".$entension;
    $file_tmp = $FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];


    $containerName = 'new'; //Enter Container Name
    $keyname = $file_name;
    $content = fopen($file_tmp, "r");
    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);

       #upload file as a block blob
       //*upload blob*
       $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $file_name, $content);
       echo "Blob upload successful";

    //upload to local mysql server
    $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]; 
    $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];     
        $folder = "image/".$filename; 
          
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "siddemo"); 
  
        //Get all the submitted data from the form
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ('$filename')"; 
  
        // Execute query 
        mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
          
        // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder: image 
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  { 
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; 
        }else{ 
            $msg = "Failed to upload image"; 
      } 
  } 
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
?>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Comment: @JimXu thank you for commenting. Apparently, I see a white blank screen as the output in the web browser. (no errors are shown)

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire I suggest you debug your application to check which line code you cannot run

Comment: @JimXu   require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; is the line breaking the code

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire Could you please tell me how you install azure blob SDK? It seams that you're missing is running composer install

Comment: @JimXu I haven't installed azure blob SDK. 
I have created a blob container in my azure account. I have used the storage account's access key as a connection string in my code ($connection). I have as well used the container's name (which is 'new') so that the uploaded file from the local computer should go and sit in the container created in azure.

From your reply, I am not sure which composer i need to install!

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/tree/1afd50bb3f89f1fed9de0b1edaf424f37a4bc13a/azure-storage-blob

Comment: @SiddarthBhaire Do you have any update?

Comment: @JimXu Thank you for the right reference. I installed the php client library to access azure blob and now the code works fine. Thank you for your valuable inputs!

Comment: @JimXu done! I have accepted the summary as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I summarize my suggestions as below

If we want to upload file to Azure Blob Storage with PHP Azure Blob SDK, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a file named composer.json in the root of your project

```
{
  "require": {
    "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "*"
  }
}
```

2. Download [composer.phar](http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) in your project root.
3. Install sdk

```
php composer.phar install
```

4. Code

```
     // name of the uploaded file
     $filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    // the physical file on a temporary uploads directory on the server
    $file = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $connectionString="";
    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
    $content = fopen($file, "r"); 
    //Upload blob
    $containerName = "upload";;
    $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $filename, $content);
    echo "File uploaded Azure Blob successfully";
```